# Show that sequence in $L^p$ which is bounded in $L^p$ and converges a.e, converges to function in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Formally, if $(f_n)_n \in L^p$, $f_n \rightarrow f$ $a.e.$ (and $f$ is measurable), and the sequence is bounded in $L^p$, then $f$ is in $L^p$ (for $p\geq 1$). My attempt of a proof is as follows, by Fatou's Lemma:
$$\int \lim \inf |f_n|^p = \int |f|^p \leq \lim \inf \int |f_n|^p$$
$$\implies \left(\int |f|^p \right)^{1/p} \leq \lim \inf \left(\int |f_n|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq M$$
Therefore $f$ is in $L^p$.

However, this feels too direct and I don't know where the $a.e.$ convergence comes into play. And yes I skipped a lot of notation.

Comment: Seems to be just an application of Fatou's lemma.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that "converges to a function in $L^p$" would normally refer to $L^p$ convergence, rather than a.e. convergence with limiting function being in $L^p$.

Comment: You replaced $\liminf |f_n|^p$ with $|f|$. This is where convergence a.e comes into play.